# Exclude description of the product from the search result of the product

Tags: sql, wordpress, search, woocommerce

Can I exclude description of the product from the search result of the product - SQL query to the database in which file? I want to search products only by Name and product tag not description.

Comment: What is your code/schema/sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the table schema, I'll assume you have a table called Product and a field called ProductName.

```
SELECT ProductName
FROM Product
WHERE ProductName like '%Some Product%'
```

If you wanted to see all fields, use the all syntax

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE ProductName like '%Some Product%'
```

If you have a very large product table, this may take some time to return.  You typically want to have your query be as selective as possible.